# How to get rid of strange white border around ListView

Tags: c#, wpf, listview

I have this very simple code for my `ListView`:

```
<Grid>
<Grid.Background>
     <SolidColorBrush Color="Black" Opacity="0.7"/>
</Grid.Background>
    <!--Date Taken Stuff here not relevant -->
    <ListView>
    <ListView.Background>
         <SolidColorBrush Color="Black" Opacity="0.7"/>
    </ListView.Background>
    </ListView>
</Grid>
```

Setting the background to the same colour as the grid it is located in to make it appear to merge in.
But I get a strange thin white boarder that changed the whole box black when I set BorderTickness=0

[image]

Comment: Your image bears no relevance to your code. Your question lacks enough detail for anyone to properly help you.

Comment: @Sheridan - not at all. I was able to reproduce the problem in less than a minute.

Comment: Ignore the date Taken park and it bears an exact resemblance to my code. I included the date taken part so the image was actually visible

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've never seen that problem before, but setting the border thickness to 0 seems to get rid of it:

```
<Grid Background="Black">
    <ListView Margin="10" BorderThickness="0" >
        <ListView.Background>
            <SolidColorBrush Color="Black" Opacity="0.7" />
        </ListView.Background>
    </ListView>
</Grid>
```

Comment: -1 The question author is clearly *not* asking how to set the `BorderThickness` to `"0"`... they said *...when I set BorderThickness=0*.

Comment: try set the Grid background in the same way you set the ListView background and let me know if you get a similar effect to mine

Comment: It seems like my ListView.Background isn't taking into consideration the opacity of 0.7

Comment: Is your problem the white border, or that the text box looks black instead of gray? If you layer a Black 0.7 opacity on top of another Black 0.7 opacity, the top box will get darker.

Comment: @Sheridan -- I agree with your comments that the original code doesn't resemble the problem. My code demonstrates a reproduction of what I perceived to be the problem (the white border), and the solution (setting border thickness to zero). In the absence of actual code that reproduces the problem, this is the best I can do.

Comment: Also, if your problem is the white border, can you add the border thickness to your XAML and reassure me that you still get the white border?

Comment: This was a mixture of two problems to be honest. The white annoying boarder which like you said dissapeared with BoarderThickness=0 and the fact that putting black 0.7 ontop of black 0.7 produced a darker colour. Which explains why the initial trial of setting BoarderTickness=0 gave me a black box. Thank you for your help in solving the mystery

Comment: No problem. And @Sheridan, sometimes you have to look past the question to see the real problem. I do this constantly with my boss. :D but thanks for the snipe downvote.

Comment: That's funny, I just came back here to check on how this question was resolved and was about to remove my down vote from your answer when I noticed your cocky remark above. Now I think that I'll leave it for that reason, rather than my original reason.

Comment: @Sheridan - no problem, I have no ego about my points. I'm just here to help.